# Delay pedal keeps setting very short delay

Tags: electric-guitar, effects-pedal

I've a TC Electronics delay pedal. You can set the delay by holding the foot switch then plucking the string in time rather than tapping.

Often though it just sets a super short delay erroneously. Other than a fault, what could cause this?

Comment: Impossible to say without investigation, but it may well be just a faulty contact in the pedal. Let a music/electronics shop investigate.

Comment: Is there any chance that the delay time you are attempting to set it to is longer than the maximum delay it can do? That could cause it to revert to its shortest time depending on the design.

Comment: Definitely not. My thought was could some noise from the guitar be getting detected as a pluck

Answer (score 2):

Try muting the string you pluck to get the delay tempo.